# New vs Old Google Analytics script

Tags: google-analytics

I got multiple profiles in same Google Analytics account, but I found that the tracking codes of newly created profiles are different. Will they affect the tracking functionality?

Old Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
```

New Code:

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X', 'mydomain.com');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like some things aren't yet supported under "Universal Analytics", the new default.

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2795983?hl=en

```
Not all data integrations are supported.
AdSense, DoubleClick, Content Experiments, and Remarketing integration aren’t supported in UA.
```

Comment: so you mean the new code is for Universal Analytics, while old code is for classic Analytics?

Comment: correct.  I'm not sure if there's per-account tracking, or if you can just hack your UA-xxxxxx id into the "old code", but I think so.  They just give you the "code" for UA by default now.